# how to make a selection from the joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

a set of posts and a set of tags:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "views",      default: 0
  end

  create_table "posts_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "tag_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "tagname"
  end
```

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE "tags" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "tagname" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "posts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar, "body" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "user_id" integer, "views" integer DEFAULT 0)
```

I need to get the count of tags that are attached to the posts(used tags).

I try to do so:

```
@tags_used_count = ::Tag.joins('posts_tags').group('tag_id').distinct.count
```

but i get follow errormessage:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::Users#index Showing
>   /home/kalinin/rails/ZSUM/app/views/layouts/_admin_header_area.html.erb
>   where line #28 raised: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tags.id:
>   SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "tags"."id") AS count_id, tag_id AS
>   tag_id FROM "tags" posts_tags GROUP BY tag_id

Answer (score 0):

Your tags table doesn't have an id column.

You should use:

```
create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.string   "tagname"
end
```

Also your posts table should have an id column. i.e.:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "views",      default: 0
  end
```

Comment: tables tags and posts have column id. it is created automatically

Answer (score 0):

Following thing should work if I got your question properly.

```
::Tag.joins(:posts).distinct.count
```

Comment: not worked(( SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tags.id: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "tags"."id") FROM "tags" posts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
::Tag.joins(:posts_tags).group('posts_tags.tag_id').distinct.count
```

Comment: not worked(( Association named 'posts_tags' was not found on Tag; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Do you mind post your model on posts, tags and posts_tags ? Setting of **has_many** and **belong_to** in these models might help.